# Append a point to a MapPolyline with here android sdk

Tags: android, sdk, here-api

I'd like to append a point to a drawn MapPolyline. So far, I'm doing it like this :

```
geoPolyline.add(newPosition);
mapPolyline.setGeoPolyline(geoPolyline);
map.removeMapObject(mapPolyline);
map.addMapObject(mapPolyline);
```

But I wonder if it's the better way (removing and readding the same element so it is re-drawn)

What do you think ?

Comment: Just calling the first two lines does not work? Does the map refresh when you call setGeoPolyline?

Comment: Actually it's working, my mistake sorry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

geoPolyline.add(newPosition);
mapPolyline.setGeoPolyline(geoPolyline);

Just add the point to the polyline and update the MapPolyline object.